# Row size too large error in django after changing charfields to textfields

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have change my database from postgresql to mysql and i got this error :
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1118, 'Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs')

Before that i had to change all charfields to textfields because of another error !

And now I have this error!

i am using RichTextField from ckeditor , do you think this may be the problem?

Comment: As the error says, you seem to store something that contains more than 65'535 bytes/characters.

Comment: none of my fields does not have more than 10,000 max_length ! and i have not create any objects yet

Comment: @Airezajavanpour: can you add the *full traceback* together with what you constructed?

Comment: tanks! my problem sloved when i delete unique=True from CharFields.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the max lengths of the row should **not** exceed 65535 characters. This includes Char, Varchar, Integer types,and Date/Time fields. So if your columns are around 10,000 characters then you can't have more than 6 columns of that length.